# How to let links opened from other apps open in a new tab in Opera instead of the current tab?

Tags: opera

I have Opera set as my default browser. When I open a link from another app and I already have a window of Opera open, the link opens in the currently active tab. I'd rather have it open in a new tab.

How do I set this? I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking Preferences > Advanced > Tabs > Reuse current tab?

Comment: There you go :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on PC, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on  Mac), then go to `Advanced` > `Tabs` and uncheck the option `Reuse current tab`.